# Will upgrading to PHP 5.3 on CentOS 6.4 cause any problems?

Tags: php, centos6

I intend to upgrade PHP from version 5.2.17 to 5.3 or higher on a CentOS 6.4 64-bit. I'm also running cPanel on the server. My question is, will it affect any other part of the server that I didn't think off? I don't mean PHP scripts on the server but libraries or programs required by other services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to test you can always disable PHP by renaming the PHP binaries to something else and see if other services break. In general PHP is not used by system maintenance utilities (the way Perl and Python are on a Linux system) so I think upgrading PHP will only affect your web applications.

Since you have the cPanel license concern, you should just take a backup of your server before the upgrade, and investigate rollback/downgrade procedures to go back to the old version of PHP if you encounter problems. Good luck!

Comment: I guess that is the only solution. I thought I'd check first in case there is a known issue since I don't know which binaries will be upgraded with PHP and will they affect anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, how are we supposed to know?

Try the upgrade on a test server and find out. That's the only way you can be sure that things will go fine in **your specific** environment.

Comment: Thank you for answering. The server is a plain CentOS installation with specific configuration. I don't think trying the upgrade on a test server will work because I will need a cPanel license for the test server.